# For Android Virtual Devices, How to Use Computer Camera?

Tags: android, camera, emulation

I'm new to android apps development. I'm trying to use the camera of my computer to catch a picture in Android Emulator. I've checked out Tom's method, but it is written in the former syntax. It has a lot of errors while I'm trying to compile them. Is there anyone have a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run the emulator with my laptop, a message pops up asking me if I want to attach the computer web cam to the emulator. I select "Yes" and it works fine.

Make sure you didn't select any "no-camera" settings in the AVD creation, and that your camera has the right drivers and whatever it needs to operate.

Comment: What platform of AVD are you using? Does the pop-up message show up when you create an AVD or when you run your codes from eclipse?

Comment: AVD was ICS (4.0) and the message pops each time I launch the AVD.

Comment: No problem :) If this solved the problem, you should accept the answer so this question is marked as "Solved"